# Deleting bulk listings but there are not any changes in available space

Tags: magento-1.9, server-setup

I have deleted about 17,000 listings from my Magento website, I have finished with Re-index and clear the cache but the available space is still 4GB as before deleting these listings. So, I should clear the cache from c panel too?

Comment: Yes  but file size or database size is 4GB?

Comment: No, the available space is 4GB.. Total space is 34GB.